# Is Xcode 14 Syntax highlighting broken for anyone else?

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax, highlight

This is in a playground, NOT in "a really complex project with imports" etc etc

What is going on lol. It's been like this since Xcode 13 on a fresh MBP M1 Max 64g ram -- but going back to 2011 stuff like this was never really a problem with a successful build (and as you can see by the log on the right side, it's successful)

[image: Enum syntax highlighting]

Edit to add, since it's unclear as to what my question was:

Here is that SAME CODE, but in another project:

Notice how the syntax highlighting is different. Why is it "broken" in the Playground?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @matt updated to clarify with another image

Comment: huh? I'm not complaining i'm asking if anyone else is running into this, and if there's maybe something i did differently on my machine vs others. Idk if it's a bug, hence why i asked here.

Comment: I have this problem as well as another where all build errors disappear immediately after a failed build. The code is no longer highlighted red and the Issue Navigator goes blank. Still searching for a solution...

Comment: @BFeher any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzpyrka its June 15th, 2023 and still no working fix. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Anybody find a fix that works consistently yet?